# How do I begin to troubleshoot aCal?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, logging, troubleshooting

I'm running [aCal](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=acal&fdid=com.morphoss.acal) on my Samsung Galaxy S / Gingerbread and it isn't updating. Adding events pushes them out to my CalDAV server, but I don't see any events.

In [aLogcat](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=alogcat&fdid=org.jtb.alogcat) I see an awful lot of errors:

> W/ActivityManager(  110): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { 
>   act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE (has extras) } from 
>   com.morphoss.acal (pid=11107, uid=10003) requires null due to receiver 
>   com.android.settings/com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider

and

> E/aCal DavParserFactory(14157): IO Exception when parsing XML

I can't figure out how much of this is [aCal](http://acal.me/wiki/Main_Page), how much is my phone, and how much is bad data from my CalDAV server ([Chandler Hub](https://hub.chandlerproject.org/welcome))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an update to [aCal](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=acal&fdid=com.morphoss.acal) has resolved my issues. So I still don't know how to troubleshoot, but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues on a Kindle Fire with iCloud. One quirky workaround is to open Settings | Servers and disable your server(s). Then re-enable them. That seems to force an update.

Edit:
a) Not sure about all calendars.
b) Right, it's a workaround, not a fix. But it address your questions:

"*I can't figure out how much of this is aCal,*"
Likely most of it, aCal being the one common element in both our observations.

"*how much is my phone, *"
Less likely, for the same reason.

"*and how much is bad data from my CalDAV server (Chandler Hub) *"
Ditto.

Comment: That works once, but a) it only syncs one calendar, not all three and b) it doesn't stick.